# What does "dupe plants" mean?

Tags: black-mirror, bandersnatch

Mohan speaks to Stefan:

> Mohan: Colin's still off exploring other dimensions. He can't bail me
> out so I need the code. First thing Monday you said. The ads are out,
> I've booked the **dupe plants**. There's some serious cash down the swanny
> if you don't deliver.

What does "dupe plants" mean in Black Mirror series?

Comment: I'm sure it's industry slang (I've not heard it used though) that refers to the process of bulk creating copies of the game for sale, and the "cash down the swanny" is relating to the time booked as well as as pre-paying for N many blank cassettes whether or not they end up with the game on them or not. I can't seem to find any useful references to make a proper answer though.

Comment: dupe = duplicate ---- swanny = the Swanee River https://wordhistories.net/2019/11/29/down-swanee/

Answer (score 2):

"[Dup<sub><sub><sup><sup>e</sup></sup></sub></sub>[licator] plants](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ogkEAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA46&ots=OsB5s-ia3t&dq=%22duplicator%20plants%22&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q=%22duplicator%20plants%22&f=false)" are factories dedicated to the reproduction of videotapes, [CDs](https://www.discusgroup.co.uk/services/cd/cd-replication/), DVDs, Blu-Ray disks, etc.

If you want a large number of copies made, you provide a high quality "master" to the duplicator who then uses the "plant" to make a pre-set number of saleable items to push out to consumers.

Since the plants run on 24/7 production schedules, they're usually booked well in advance. Providing the master on time is essential. If you miss your slot, you might have to wait weeks or even months for another one, hence why many PC games entered production filled with bugs.